# pyspark write failed with StackOverflowError

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, fixed-width

I was planning to convert fixed-width to Parquet in AWS Glue,
my data has around 1600 columns, and around 3000 rows.
Seems like when i try to write the spark dataframe (in parquet), I am getting "StackOverflow" issue.
Issue is seen even when i do count(), show() etc.
I tried calling cache(),repartition() but still see this error.

Code works if I reduce number of columns to 500.

Please help

below is my code

```
    data_df = spark.read.text(input_path) 

    schema_df = pd.read_json(schema_path)
    df = data_df

    for r in schema_df.itertuples():
        df = df.withColumn(
            str(r.name), df.value.substr(int(r.start), int(r.length))
        )
    df = df.drop("value")

    df.write.mode("overwrite").option("compression", "gzip").parquet(output_path) # FAILING HERE
```

Stack trace below.

```
> 
2021-11-10 05:00:13,542 ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(70)): Error from Python:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/conv_fw_2_pq.py", line 148, in <module>
    partition_ts=parsed_args.partition_timestamp,
  File "/tmp/conv_fw_2_pq.py", line 125, in process_file
    df.write.mode("overwrite").option("compression", "gzip").parquet(output_path)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 839, in parquet
    self._jwrite.parquet(path)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
**py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o7066.parquet.
: java.lang.StackOverflowError**
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.references(Expression.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$references$1.apply(Expression.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$references$1.apply(Expression.scala:88)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.references(Expression.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$references$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$references$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Stream.scala:497)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Stream.scala:497)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official Spark documentation has the following description:
This method(`withColumn`) introduces a projection internally. Therefore, calling it multiple times, for instance, via loops in order to add multiple columns can generate big plans which can cause performance issues and even ***StackOverflowException***. To avoid this, use `**select()**` with the multiple columns at once.

It is recommended that you first construct the **select list**, and then use the select method to construct a new dataframe.